# Position text at x, y in grid

Tags: javascript

I have a class, which basically draws a 16x30 grid.

Ideally, I would like to be able to execute:

`OSD.setCursor(x y);`

`OSD.print('Text');`

and have it position the word `Text` at position `x, y` with each character of `Text` positioned in the correct location in the grid.

Here's what I have so far:

```js
class MAX7456 {
  constructor() {
    this.items = null;
    this.divs = null;
  }

  begin() {
    var ratioH = 16,
        ratioW = 30;
    
    var parent = $('<div />', {
        class: 'grid', 
        width: ratioW  * 25,
        height: ratioH  * 18
    }).addClass('grid').appendTo('body');

    for (var i = 0; i < ratioH; i++) {
        for(var p = 0; p < ratioW; p++) {
            this.divs = $('<div />', {
                width: 25 - 1, 
                height: 18 - 1
            }).appendTo(parent);
            
            this.items = $('<span />', {
                width: 25 - 1, 
                height: 18 - 1,
                style: "padding-left: 2px;"
            }).appendTo(this.divs);
        }
    }
  }

  setCursor(x, y) {
    $('div > span:nth-child(2n-1)').text(function (i, txt) {
     $(this).append(i)
     i++;
     //console.log(txt + $(this).next().text());
    });
  }
  print (txt) {
  } 
}

var OSD = new MAX7456();
OSD.begin(); // create grid
OSD.setCursor(0, 0); // set text at cursor (x, y)
OSD.print("Label 2");
```

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.grid {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-width: 1px 0 0 1px;
}

.grid div {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fulvio/nsYyc/1136/)

Comment: I had exactly question like this. Let me give you the answer what i worked with.

Comment: @Inuka Thanks for that!

Comment: @fuzz, if you place cursor on any number , it should change to Text right?

Comment: @NagaSaiA Sure, yes

Answer (score 1):

Now this may seems not the ideal solution looking for, In that case my apologies. My requirement was to create a tiled grid based on an image so this how i managed to do it.

- Total tile count can be vary as you need. (My case 2500 tiles)
- When you adjust the image size that will determine what size of the tile can be.

```js
(function($) {
  var imagePadding = 0;
  var pluginName = "tiles",
    defaults = {
      x: 2, // tiles in x axis
      y: 2, // tiles in y axis
      gap: {
        x: 1,
        y: 1
      }
    };

  function Plugin(elem, options) {

    options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

    var $elem = $(elem).wrap("<div class='tiles-wrapper' />"),
      width = $elem.outerWidth(),
      height = $elem.outerHeight(),
      n_tiles = options.x * options.y,
      tiles = [];

    $elem.parent(".tiles-wrapper").css({
      position: "relative",
      width: width,
      height: height
    });

    for (var $i = 0; $i < n_tiles; $i++) {
      if ($i >= imagePadding) {
        tiles.push("<div class='tile' data-id='" + $i + "' data-clipboard-text='" + $i + "'>" + $i + "</div>");
      } else {
        tiles.push("<div class='tile' data-id='" + $i + "' data-clipboard-text='" + $i + "'></div>");
      }
    }

    var $tiles = $(tiles.join(""));

    // Hide original image and insert tiles in DOM
    $elem.hide().after($tiles);

    // Set backgrounds
    $tiles.css({
      float: "left",
      width: (width / options.x) - (options.gap.x || options.gap),
      height: (height / options.y) - (options.gap.y || options.gap),
      marginRight: options.gap.x || options.gap,
      marginBottom: options.gap.y || options.gap,
      backgroundImage: "url(" + $elem[0].src + ")",
      lineHeight: (height / options.y) - (options.gap.y || options.gap) + "px",
      textAlign: "center"
    });

    // Adjust position
    $tiles.each(function() {
      var pos = $(this).position();
      this.style.backgroundPosition = -pos.left + "px " + -pos.top + "px";
    });

  }

  $.fn[pluginName] = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
      new Plugin(this, options);
    });
  };

}(jQuery));

window.onload = function() {
  $('#img').tiles({
    x: 21.909,
    y: 21.909
  });

  $(".tile").click(function() {
    console.log($(this).data("id"));
  });

};
```

```css
.tiles-wrapper {
  z-index: 999;
}

.tile:hover {
  opacity: .80;
  filter: alpha(opacity=80);
  background: #fecd1f!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="banner-head"></div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="image-holder">
            <img id="img" src="data:image/gif;base64,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"
              alt="event picture" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Mmm, there's a lot of stuff going on in there. Thanks for providing this example. Unfortunately I'm after a function to be able to position text appropriately according to wherever the cursor is placed on: X, Y. I guess I could use this for its event features in the future, however what I'm really after is positioning and drawing the text.

Comment: Did you find the solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't.

Comment: I created this fiddle. The code is not originally mine but it does what you need. https://jsfiddle.net/The_Killer/nLwqjo8u/

Comment: That's pretty much what I'm after but the coordinates should be `0, 0` for top-left not bottom-left and I want to be able to position the words in the correct coordinates.

Comment: Here check [this update](https://jsfiddle.net/The_Killer/nLwqjo8u/2/) now. Let me know if that's ok for you to post in here.